# Feign Client Exception [302]

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to make 2 microservices communicate with Open Feign. The two microservices are student and address.
When I'm trying to call the method written in feign client I'm getting this exception

feign.FeignException: [302] during [GET] to [http://ADDRESS-SERVICE/address/student/1] [AddressClient#getParticularStudentAddressById(Long)]: [{"addressId":1,"city":"Greater Noida","country":"India","studentId":1}]

This is my Feign Client in student microservice

```
@FeignClient(value = "ADDRESS-SERVICE", path = "/address")
public interface AddressClient {
@GetMapping("/student/{studentId}")
public ResponseEntity<Address> getParticularStudentAddressById(@PathVariable Long studentId);
}
```

This is address controller method

```
@GetMapping("/student/{studentId}")
public ResponseEntity getParticularStudentAddressById(@PathVariable Long studentId) {
Address response = addressService.getAddressOfStudent(studentId);
return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.FOUND);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing and what is leading to this exception?

I'm getting the JSON response I'm expecting in error message but not as a POJO object.